# How to mass add records to Chatter streams from Lightning Interface?

Tags: chatter

Our users love Chatter and Chatter streams, but following each single record manually is cumbersome. Is it possible to run reports, or use listviews, and follow records / add records to Chatter Stream from the user interface?

Comment: I don't think this answers your question as such but you can [interact with Streams through the Connect API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/177928/create-a-custom-chatter-stream-from-apex-connectapi).